# Querying subgraph by ID fails but other properties work. How to query a subgraph by ID?

Tags: filter, subgraph

I'm trying to validate subgraph IDs in https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v3.

Given the token `id: "0x419D0d8BdD9aF5e606Ae2232ed285Aff190E711b"` for `FUN`.

```
{
    tokens(where: {
    symbol: "FUN"
    # id: "0x419D0d8BdD9aF5e606Ae2232ed285Aff190E711b"  # <-- returns nothing
  }){
    symbol
    name
    id
  }
}
```

When I query by `token.symbol`, I see the right contract ID in the result.  However when querying using `token.id`, the result is empty.

When I used the contract addresses for `DAI (0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f)` and `WETH (0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2)`, results were returned

Why is this not consistent?

Answer (score 0):

You should transform addresses to lowercase. Once you insert the address in lowercase, you will get the result:

[image: see the result of your query here]